# take tokens from the same line in r programming

Tags: r, parsing, tokenize

using R programming ,i need to take tokens ngram=2 from a file.

the problem is that it combines the lines , and some tokens has part at the end of line and the other part at the start of the next line

```
Req_tok <-jobs %>% unnest_tokens(ngram,POSITION, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
```

in the file jobs  i have the first two lines:

```
it architect

it helpdesk support agents
```

i get tokens like:

```
it architect
architect it
it helpdesk
and so on ....
```

what to do in order not to get tokens like "architect it"

i want to tokenize every line separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `collapse = FALSE` in your `unnest_tokens`:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

jobs %>% 
  unnest_tokens(ngram, POSITION, token = "ngrams", n = 2, collapse = FALSE)
```

**Result:**

```
               ngram
1       it architect
2        it helpdesk
2.1 helpdesk support
2.2   support agents
```

Remember to convert your string vector to character if it is a factor variable, otherwise `unnest_token` will throw you an error.

**Data:**

```
jobs = data.frame(POSITION = c("it architect", "it helpdesk support agents"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```